# Hybris CategoryProductRelation type as ItemModel?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Quick question... so in Hybris, I have a query similar to this:

```
"SELECT {CPR:pk} FROM {CategoryProductRelation as CPR},  ...."
```

Basically, I need to extract the Product Code and Category Code from Java which I think are available as source / target respectively but my question is, just like there's ProductModel, CategoryModel, etc. is there anything like that for CategoryProductRelation?, probably something like a generic RelationModel to simply extract source / target and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to `JOIN` in the entities like this

```
SELECT {CPR:pk}, {c.code} FROM {CategoryProductRelation as CPR 
JOIN Category AS c on {CPR.source} = {c.PK} } WHERE ...
```

Also, you can do that in the Service Layer by simply calling your query and accessing the properties right from the relation type:

```
..
CategoryProductRelationModel model = result.get(0)
String categoryCode = ((CategoryModel)model.getSource()).getCode()
```

Depending on your **amount of data**, this could be pretty **ineffecient**.